# Sorting, updating and presenting async response data in a HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, asynchronous

I've got an app that issues multiple async calls to a backend; each async response will be an array of `{date, string}` values.

I'd like to present the responses of each of these async calls as they arrive, in a sorted table in my web browser (ordered by date).  As subsequent responses to the other async calls arrive, I want the sorted table to be updated in real time.

For example, the first async response might be `[{'2012-02-10', 'ABC'}, {'2012-01-19', 'DEF'}, {'2012-03-01', 'GHI'}]`, and I'd want to see something like `<table><tr><td>2012-01-19</td><td>DEF</td></tr><tr><td>2012-02-10</td><td>ABC</td></tr><tr><td>2012-03-01</td><td>GHI</td></tr></table>` rendered in my browser immediately.

If a second async response of `[{'2011-12-09', 'JKL'}]` appears some time later, I want the HTML to then be changed to `<table><tr><td>2011-12-09</td><td>JKL</td></tr><tr><td>2012-01-19</td><td>DEF</td></tr><tr><td>2012-02-10</td><td>ABC</td></tr><tr><td>2012-03-01</td><td>GHI</td></tr></table>`

The effect I'm after is to have a table of results in my browser, being progressively updated with **sorted** data as the various async responses turn up.  The table would grow in size as each new async response is received, as the new `{date, string}` elements appear in the correct date sequence with the data that's already being displayed.

This probably isn't a unique scenario, so I'm guessing there's a way of doing this that would be considered 'best practice' - possibly using jQuery UI.  If so, could someone please point me towards a 'howto' or example? - I haven't been able to find anything suitable using Google.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried searching in google? It shows up many existing solutions. Is none of them useful for you?

Comment: I tried, but maybe I was using the wrong search terms - it's hard to describe what I'm after in a few words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with this

```
<script>
function my_func()
{
var myarray = ["2012-02-10, ABC", "2012-01-19, DEF", "2012-03-01, GHI"];
var table_content = '';
var temp_arr = '';
for(var i in myarray)
{
    myarray.sort();
    temp_arr = myarray[i].split(',');
    table_content = table_content + '<tr><td>'+temp_arr[1]+'</td><td>'+temp_arr[0]+'</td></tr>'
}
table_content = '<table>'+table_content+'</table>'
document.getElementById('mytable').innerHTML = table_content;
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="clickme" onclick="my_func();"/>
<div id="mytable"></div>
```

In place of calling that function on button click you can run that function on sucessful call of your function and then fill up the html.

I hope this helps